# Spring 3.05- issue with @Value - returning null

Tags: spring

`@Value` is returning null as I am trying to read properties.

Below is my configuration:

```
<util:properties 
     id="applicationProps"
     location="/WEB-INF/spring/application.properties" />
```

Below is the code that I have in a custom tag:

```
private @Value("#{applicationProps.staticResourceUrl}") String staticResourceUrl;
```

Comment: A custom tag? Does spring control its lifecycle? Is it in a scanned package?

Comment: Hi Dave,I am not sure how I can make spring control the life cycle of the custom tag or have it scanned? As of now, I wrote the custom tag in same package where I am trying to use it in JSP.

Comment: In order to be recognized it would need to be in a package that spring is scanning for annotations. Not sure if it would also need to be annotated as a component.

Comment: I added @Component annotation in the custom tag, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I am able to access properties from JSP as follows - <spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['staticResourceUrl']" var="staticResourceUrl"/>

Comment: I added the tag lib file in the same package where Spring is scanning - <context:component-scan base-package="guest"/>, also the tag lib file has the @Component annotation. But, it does not seem to work!

Comment: Jetty (which I am using to deploy the app), does mention that both the staticResourceUrlTagHandler and applicationProps are initialized in following log statement - "INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory"

Answer (score 0):

If the props file `application.properties` contained a property called `staticResourceUrl` then import it via:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/application.properties"/>
```

and use it via:

```
@Value("${staticResourceUrl}") private String staticResourceUrl;
```

Comment: I had done what Paul mentioned above. Also, have the @Component annotation. Still I am getting null.

Comment: below is in my application.properties - staticResourceUrl=http://localhost-static-webserver:8082. Below is in my spring-servlet.xml - <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/application.properties"/>

Comment: this is my tag - @Component
public class StaticResourceUrlTagHandler extends TagSupport  {
 @Value("${staticResourceUrl}") private String staticResourceUrl;

Comment: You do have something like this in your context? :     <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar"/>

Comment: Yes. Does the oreder matter? <context-component-scan> tag precedes <context-property-placeholder> in my XML file.

Comment: If you ramp up the debug on Spring can you see if you can spot your class being constructed as a bean? I seem to recall that auto-wiring gets logged

Comment: Hi Paul, I ran it thru debugger and I confirmed that the properties are being loaded. I have also tried the following - 1. moved "<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/application.properties"/>" to applicationContext.xml   2. added the following in web.xml -     <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>. I am still getting null.

Answer (score 0):

Custom tag lifecycle is not usually handled by spring but one thing you can do is extend

`org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag`

and do

```
WebApplicationContext wac = getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext();
String url = wac.getEnvironment().getProperty("some.property");
```

in the `doStartTagInternal()` method.